# Designer workflows not working after migration from Sharepoint Foundation 2010 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow, migration

We have a problem after migrating a site collection from SharePoint Foundation 2010 SP1 to a new SharePoint Foundation 2013 SP1 farm, following Microsoft guidelines

Here are the details:

Site collection main site has a Sharepoint Designer workflow associated to a list. There are 30 subsites from same template with libraries and lists with also Designer workflow.

Root site workflow is identical to subsite workflows: same configuration, same steps and actions and same security. Root site and subsites same configuration and same features enabled

And, if I try to open with Sharepoint Designer workflow in the root site, it opens, I can edit it, I can publish it, and workflow runs without any problems, doing its jobs.

But I try to open any of the subsites workflows with Sharepoint Designer, it does not open throwing the following message:
ERROR WORKFLOW LOADING CONFIGURATION FILE
[image]

And then:
SHAREPOINT DESIGNER CANNOT SHOW THE ELEMENT
PROBABLE CAUSES:
- FIELE WAS REMOVED FROM SITE ((BUT FILES EXIST IN THE PROPER FOLDER)
- WEB SITE IS FINDING PROBLEMS  (-AND SHAREPOINT LOGS ARE NOT TELLING ANYTHING)

[image]
We've tried everything we found, even deleting Sharepoint Desginer local caches, but with no effect.

Obviusly, in the Sharepoint Foundation 2010 site collections all workflows are operative, in the root site and in all subsites.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: Can you try create a new workflow with a test action? _only for discard if there's something wrong with the creation of workflows linked to lists._ Example: create a simple workflow who has a action that write some text in the workflow history (when a item is created in the linked list).

Comment: which version of sharepoint designer are you using? if you migrate from 2010 to 2013 you can no longer edit those workflows with sharepoint designer 2010 you need 2013